# How can I make the background behind a <legend> transparent?

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get the background of a <legend> element to be transparent.  See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hWZa6/ (tested in Chrome and Firefox)

The effect I am trying to accomplish is actually moving the <legend> element below the top border of the containing <frameset> element, but nothing I do makes the top border complete.  It is always missing the bit of the line where the legend would be, whether I try to use transparency or position:
http://cl.ly/image/1W043h0I3f0A/Edit%20this%20Fiddle%20-%20jsFiddle.jpg

How can I make the area of border where the legend WOULD be, complete?

Comment: could set `display: none;` if you really need the legend div at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `position:absolute` to the `legend`. Optionally add `position:relative` to the `fieldset` so you can move things around.

Answer (score 1):

You can position it off the screen,

```
position:absolute; left:-999em;
```

Or your favorite offsetting technique that's compatible with screenreaders and such. ( Perhaps investigate boilerplate's image replacement styles )

Answer (score 1):

Try this, just hide the fieldset border and wrap the element in a div with a border.  http://jsfiddle.net/hWZa6/15/

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Test</legend>
    The top border is never fully visible, despite the legend being set <code>visibility: hidden</code>.
    <div id="A">
        <div id="B">Upon applying <code>visibility: hidden</code> this div becomes transparent, and the red div behind it is fully visible.</div>
    </div>        
  </fieldset>
</div>
​
fieldset { border: none; }
#wrapper { border: 1px solid black; }
legend { display: block }
#A { background-color: red; width: 300px; height: 150px; padding: 10px;}
#B { background-color: blue; width: 400px; height: 100px;}​
```

Comment: While this works, it requires the HTML to be changed. If the HTML could be changed, why not get rid of the `<legend>` element itself, and replace it with another element like a <p> or something?

Comment: That's true, there are a ton of ways to display like he wants.  If he wants the legend to show and have a solid top border this is how to do it.  Or change legend to a different tag.  but just hiding the legend only accomplishes one of two things he asked.  so really it's either change the html, accept the legend not showing, or use javascript to alter the dom.

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS for the `legend` element.

```
legend { margin-left: -9999px; }
```

Comment: Why not just turn the display off?

Comment: @RajeshJAdvani: Turning the display off would mess with the `fieldset` element's top-border. Specifically, the half-height space above the top-border.

Comment: You can always fix that using a margin or padding. Positioning an element at a large distance to the left is a hack. While it works, I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to, or can't change the HTML, and you don't need the legend text to be visible, you can turn the display off.

```
legend { display: none; }
```

If you do have control over the HTML, then @user1289347's solution would work, though it requires adding wrapper elements.